# Devise 'Unknown action' when overwriting registration controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to overwrite `Devise` registration controller and here is my setup:

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :token

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      render 'create.js', :success => true
    else
      render 'create.js', :success => false
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
(...)
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions', :registrations => 'registrations'}
match 'registrations/create'        => 'registrations#create'   , :as => :user_register
# not matter if i'll put `match 'registrations/create'` line above or under the `devise_for` line
(...)
```

And it all (when i'll point my browser to `registrations/create`) gives me an error:

> ### Unknown action
>
> Could not find devise mapping for path "/registrations/create". This
> may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside
> the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do match
> "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a
> Devise controller bypassing the router. If so, you can explicitly tell
> Devise which mapping to use: @request.env["devise.mapping"] =
> Devise.mappings[:user]

I've found some threads describing similar issue but they were not helpfull at all. Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message clearly states, you need to wrap your Devise routes in a block like so:

```
devise_scope :user do
  match 'registrations/create' => 'registrations#create', :as => :user_register
end
```

Devise does not accept routes outside of that block.